# why do i only see one tweet in the search from API Query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, twitter, twitter-search

I'm using the following query:

[https://twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=from:_adeel&count=5&include_entities=true&include_rts=true](https://twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=from%3a_adeel&count=5&include_entities=true&include_rts=true)

and I would like to see the last 5 tweets from this user. You can see that the [user](https://twitter.com/#!/_adeel) has many more than 2 tweets yet the query only returns 2 tweets. I'm following the twitter search [API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) and I fail to see what I'm doing wrong. I prefer to use the twitter search API because I want to perform the search on the client side without authentication and rate limits.

Do you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Also worth noting - even if you are not authenticated you are still subject to rate limits. The docs state "... all requests coming from an IP address are applied to a Search Rate Limit." https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) in the documentation, the search API is an index of recent tweets, between 6-9 days old. It looks like the other tweets from the user you linked to are just outside this window.

So to summarize - you are not doing anything wrong. This is simply a limitation of the Twitter API.

Comment: And next item: `You cannot use the Search API to find Tweets older than about a week.`